# Content was blocked because it was not signed by a valid security certificate

Tags: certificate, jmeter

> Content was blocked because it was not signed by a valid security
>   certificate

It happened when I try recording in JMeter. However, it works fine in JMeter non-recording mode.

Any thoughts and ideas how to solve this is very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You need to accept the certificate of JMeter by first navigating to the Https part or your webapp.

Ensure you use last jmeter version and a jdk 7 or 8.

Read this:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder
- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Since 2.10 version JMeter is capable of generating self-signed SSL certificate on-the-fly so perhaps something is wrong with your environment configuration. The following checklist should resolve your issue:

1. JAVA_HOME environment variable is set and pointing to the latest Java SE SDK version
2. PATH environment variable contains /bin folder of JDK installation
3. JMeter respects aforementioned variables (to be totally sure add them to JMeter startup script)
4. Clean browser session (delete full browser history, cache, etc.)

Reference material:

- [TestRecording210](https://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/TestRecording210)
- [Recording HTTPS Traffic with JMeter's Proxy Server](http://blazemeter.com/blog/recording-https-traffic-jmeters-proxy-server)